# How do I configure jest to give coverage on Selenium tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

I just started using jest for testing my JavaScript project. I was using mocha and chai, but I couldn't get coverage information on my component tests, which use babel and Selenium, so I thought I'd try jest. I've converted my tests over to use jest and they are working but again, the Selenium tests do not give coverage information. I have a few unit tests that don't use Selenium, and I'm getting coverage data from them. If I disable the unit tests, the coverage numbers are basically zeroes across the board (though not *exactly* zero, there are a handful of lines that do get covered).

I've found a few blogs and SO questions addressing this problem, but their solutions are out-of-date (i.e. bug in jest, fixed in version 0.9.0. I'm using version 29.3.1). My `jest.config.js` contains this:

```js
{
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
    coverageProvider: 'babel',
    coverageReporters: [ 'html' ]
}
```

I'm using node.js v16.13.0 on Windows. My dependencies are:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.2.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "mocha": "^10.1.0",
    "rewire": "^6.0.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.6.0",
    "sinon": "^14.0.1"
}
```

How can I get coverage information from the Selenium tests?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying for about a week to get code coverage with Jest and Selenium-webdriver. It just does not work. I tried a different approach using nyc reporter. After the Selenium tests run, I use JavascriptExecutor to return the value of `window.__coverage__`, stringify it, save it as `output.json` in `nyc_output` directory and then run `nyc report --reporter=lcov`.

Magic. I get the code coverage report.

```
const data = await driver.executeScript("return window.__coverage__");
fs.promises.writeFile(".nyc_output/output.json", JSON.stringify(data));
```

It's a little hacky and not a long term solution, but meets my requirements until I can understand why Jest is not working.

Hopefully we get a better answer from someone else. But I have searched the internet high and low and have not seen any working examples of how to get code coverage for Selenium with Jest or even Mocha and nyc.

Comment: Thanks for this info, but where did you put the code you included above? I have a number of .js files, each of which contains tests, but there isn't a "main" file that runs everything, I just run "jest" and it runs all the tests in all the files in my test directory.